# How to use edge as constraint when drawing graph but not when computing rank

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a `dot` graph, and I am using the `constraint=false` because for some of the edges, I don't want the edge to affect the rank of the nodes. Unfortunately, it appears that this means that the `dot` engine doesn't use that edge for layout of nodes within a rank, and it also seems to do a worse job at routing the edge itself. For example, see this graph:

```
digraph G {

subgraph G1 {
    a1 -> b1
    d1 -> b1
    b1 -> c1
    a1 -> c1 [constraint=false]
}

subgraph G2 {
    a2 -> b2
    d2 -> b2
    b2 -> c2
    a2 -> c2
}

}
```

[see online](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A%0Asubgraph%20G1%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a1%20-%3E%20b1%0A%20%20%20%20d1%20-%3E%20b1%0A%20%20%20%20b1%20-%3E%20c1%0A%20%20%20%20a1%20-%3E%20c1%20%5Bconstraint%3Dfalse%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Asubgraph%20G2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a2%20-%3E%20b2%0A%20%20%20%20d2%20-%3E%20b2%0A%20%20%20%20b2%20-%3E%20c2%0A%20%20%20%20a2%20-%3E%20c2%0A%7D%0A%0A%7D)

the `a1 -> c1` edge could be routed left of the `b1` node, but isn't. I don't want `a1 -> c1` to be used for computing rank.

Is there a way to get the "best of both worlds" here? I.e. a way to get the better layout (like the `a2 -> c2` edge) but not use the edge for computing rank?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to *not* use a edge for ranking, but use it for the layout (without affecting the ranking). Edges with `constraint=false` seem to be laid out after the placement of the nodes is determined.

What's left are some "hacks", not sure whether they are applicable in a generic manner for all of your use cases.

For example, if you make sure that the nodes linked with such an edge are mentioned *before* the others, the resulting layout is - at least in this example - improved:

```
subgraph G1 {
    d1, a1;
    a1 -> b1
    d1 -> b1


    b1 -> c1
    a1 -> c1 [constraint=false]
}
```

[example](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A%0Asubgraph%20G1%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20d1%2C%20a1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20a1%20-%3E%20b1%0A%20%20%20%20d1%20-%3E%20b1%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20b1%20-%3E%20c1%0A%20%20%20%20a1%20-%3E%20c1%20%5Bconstraint%3Dfalse%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Asubgraph%20G2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a2%20-%3E%20b2%0A%20%20%20%20d2%20-%3E%20b2%0A%20%20%20%20b2%20-%3E%20c2%0A%20%20%20%20a2%20-%3E%20c2%0A%7D%0A%0A%7D)

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. I'll see if I can make it work.